# Creating tool for finding catchments, watersheds and channel network in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arctoolbox, hydrography

I've been working in QGIS for a while, but I have to use ArcGIS from now on. In QGIS I made a tool in the Graphical Modeler, in order to ease a process I had to do several times. I've been told this is possible in ArcGIS as well, but I would like some hints, as the names aren't the same as I'm used to.

My old tool used a DEM/Raster and then did the following (Using SAGA)

Fill Sinks -> Catchment Area -> Channel Network -> Watershed Basins

Simple tool for finding catchments, watersheds and the channel network. Which tools would do something similar in ArcGIS? I've been reading up on it, but there seems to be several?

The function of the tool is finding where the water flows, and the catchments/watersheds to these channels.

Comment: do you have spatial analyst ? you'll find these tools in the hydrology toolbox http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_the_Hydrology_tools

Comment: Yes I do have that. I can see that Fill, Flow Direction and Watershed looks like the functions I need. But in what order should they be used?

Comment: Exactly the order you state in your comment.